# Git Branching and Rebasing, Is My Script Safe?

Tags: git, bash, git-rebase, git-bash

I work in a team where we do all of our development in feature branches, and when features are complete we merge them back into our main branch (called development). Periodically we will do formal usability testing or demos of our software, so we make branches specifically for those tests where we alter some parts of our configuration for the test environment before we merge into our testing branch.

As a super lazy person, I decided to script the process of creating the staging branch, but I am new enough to git that I want to be sure that I haven't written a function that will come back and bite me later. So here's my function (all of this is in my .bashrc):

```
alias updateDev='git stash && git rebase -m -X theirs development && git stash pop'
function newTest() {
    updateDev
    git checkout -b staging-test-$1
    git push origin staging-test-$1
}
```

Here's the intended usage:

```
newTest 1.3.7
```

And here's what I think is happening:

- All changes are stashed
- The branch "development" is checked out and
  updated
- Changes are reapplied (Note: No development happens directly
  on development, so there should never be changes)
- The staging branch is created using the passed in version number, matching the contents of the development branch
- The staging branch is pushed to a new remote branch on origin

Is anything in this code going to work differently than I expect it to, or can anything in this code be improved to work more reliably?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Don't use an alias in a script. Just define a function called `updateDev` that does the same thing.

Comment: One of the fundamental rules of programming is that, no matter how careful you are and how many obscure corner cases you consider and code properly for, there will always be at least one scenario that should never happen, and can in fact be proven to be impossible, yet it happens anyway.

Comment: @twalberg: "Every program has at least one bug, and at least one unnecessary line of code. Therefore every program can be reduced to a single line of code with a bug in it. :)" [I saw this many years ago, but found again just now in a comment at http://www.informationisbeautiful.net/visualizations/million-lines-of-code/, also http://infiniteundo.com/post/22292945729/rapid-infrastructure-tools-you-can-use-even-if-you ... no attribution, but it might be an Alan Perlis quote, perhaps.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, much depends on how paranoid you want to be.

One obvious thing you could do is verify that there is at least, or exactly, one argument to the function, so that `$1` expands to something:

```
case $# in
1) ;;
*) echo "usage: newTest <name>" 1>&2; return 1;;
esac
```

Another is to make sure the branch name is valid.  Per `git-check-ref-format`:

```
local ref

ref=$(git check-ref-format --normalize "refs/heads/staging-test-$1") ||
    { echo "'staging-test-$1' is not a valid branch name" 1>&2; return 1; }
```

although then you probably want to strip refs/heads/ off again:

```
ref=${ref#refs/heads/}
```

after which you can use `$ref` to avoid repeating the `staging-test-` part.

Then: what if that branch name already exists?  Is that an error, or should it be replaced?  (To make it an error, check for `git checkout -b` failure, for instance.)

Then: what if stash or rebase fails?  You say "there should never be changes", but presumably the point of saving and applying the stash is that there are *some* changes.  It's not really clear to me what `updateDev` is *intended* to do.  It does not check what the current branch is, it simply rebases the current branch (whatever it is) onto `development` using `-X theirs` (which means keep "our" version of everything).

Moreover, suppose there are *no* changes to stash, but there *is* already an existing stash.  In this case, `git stash` will exit successfully after printing `No local changes to save`.  The `updateDev` script will then run the rebase, and assuming it succeeds, will pop (apply and drop) the top-most existing stash.  This is almost certainly not a good thing.

Last: what if `git checkout -b` and/or `git push` fail?  (E.g., due to running out of disk space or something equally terrible, or simply because the name supplied already existed.)